# Protractor Error - @types/jasmine' is not in the npm registry

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

I am trying to install protractor but receiving following error.
command: 
`npm install -g protractor`

```
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 no such package available : @types/jasmine
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 '@types/jasmine' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'protractor'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     F:\temp\chrome downloads\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: you may need to install the latest version of nodejs. Can you try with latest one

Comment: I installed the latest version 7.0.0. but still seeing the same issue

Comment: have you ran npm install after installing nodejs? if not please do it

Comment: @SureshSalloju what is this supposed to do? I am looking for global installation of Protractor. NPM install is to be run from a  project directory right?

Answer (score 4):

I came across this issue today and my problem was that I had set a custom registry within the npm config file. Have you ever used "npm set registry"?
If so, you can manually tell npm where to look for the '@types' registry with the following command:

npm config set @types:registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from the fact that you're using a private registry that has not yet added support for `@organization` packages. 
In my case, I was using [Sonatype Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products-sonatype) and my version didn't have support for those types of packages. @Willie Valdez's suggestion is probably the best solution for you, right now.

Also, check if you have a `.npmrc` file in your home directory or in your project directory. The registry might be there. If that's the case, just rename the file to `npmrc_bak` or something else until you install the package and then revert back to its original name.

Answer (score 0):

You can also include a `.npmrc` file in your current project with the below details:

```
@angular:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
@types:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
@ngtools:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
@angular-cli:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

its handy and resuable across new projects.